# The height of 5-balnced tree is O(logn)

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

Binary tree with external leaves is a 5-balanced tree if the path from the root to the farthest external leaf is no more than 5 times as long as the path from the root to the nearest external leaf, and if his right and left subtrees are 5-balanced too. Show that the height of such a tree is O(logn).

I was trying to prove it by finding the minimum number of nodes in such a tree with height h and then saying that the height of the tree is at most the log of this number, but I'm not sure how to find it.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure how to find what?  Your approach sounds promising; where specifically did you get stuck?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the tree has depth $D$. Then all leaves are at distance at least $D/5$ from the root, which means that the tree contains the full binary tree of depth $D/5$ as a subtree. This implies that $n \geq 2^{D/5}$, and so $D = O(\log n)$.

Note that this argument doesn't use the recursive part of the definition.